# How to find $\lim_{n \to \infty}\Sigma_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin(\pi x)^2}{i^2}$?

Tags: integration, summation, riemann-sum

I am trying to find:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\cfrac{\sin(\pi x)^2}{i^2}$$

using maple command:

`limit(Sum(sin(Pi*x)^2/i^2, i = 1 .. n), n = infinity);`

gives:

$\cfrac{1}{6} \left( \sin \left( \pi \,x \right)  \right) ^{2}{\pi }^{2}$

How to find $\lim_{n \to \infty}\Sigma_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin(\pi x)^2}{i^2}$?

Comment: You have an $x$ in the sum but the summation index is $i$. So did you mean $\sin(\pi \color{blue}{i})^2$ instead? Otherwise, the $\sin(\pi x)^2$ is just a constant with respect to $n$ and $i$, so would come all the way outside the limit.

Comment: It is a simple question where you have to use $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Comment: I am guessing what you wrote is not what the original problem actually said.  Otherwise that Khan Academy hint is nonsensical.

Comment: @GEdgar that's correct this is another problem not on the Khan academy site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an $x$ in the sum with $\sin(\pi x)^2$ ,it will just get out of the Summation. Thus,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\Sigma_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin(\pi x)^2}{i^2}$$
$$=\sin(\pi x)^2\lim_{n \to \infty}\Sigma_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i^2}$$
$$= \frac{π^2×\sin(\pi x)^2}{6}$$

If you mean $\sin(\pi \color{red}{i})^2$ instead,
$\sin(\pi \color{red}{i})^2 = 0  \forall i \in N $. So 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\Sigma_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin(\pi i)^2}{i^2} = 0$$

Comment: More interesting and not quite as trivial would be $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\sin(\pi i/n)^2}{i^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin^2(\pi x)}{i^2}=\sin^2(\pi x)\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\sin^2(\pi x)$$
since:
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i^2}=\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
Where $\zeta$ is the [zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function)